# REST Api - JSON - "Cannot deserialize instance of object out of START_ARRAY token"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

The issue in question is as follows:-

I have a POJO with a list of Apple objects , say `applesList`.

This is stored in Cosmos DB.

When `applesList` is `null`, the get endpoint works fine. I get the Pojo as is.

When `applesList` is populated with apples, i get the error as given in the Title.

How do i fix this?

Json that works with get  :-

```
{
  "userId" : "123",
  "applesList" : null
}
```

Json that gives stated error on get, applesList is populated by api :-

```
{
  "userId" : "123",
  "applesList" : [
       {
          "color" : "red",
          "weight" : "150 g"
       },
       {
          "color" : "green",
          "weight" : "200 g"
       }
   ]
}
```

Edit :- missed mentioning Cosmos DB SQL API

Comment: Stop explaining code, show it, what is the incoming json, what is the actual java class involved that you want to map to?

Comment: Make sure your pojo and nested apple object is extending Serializable interface

Comment: Post your json request

Comment: @mad_fox posted

Comment: @Suraj tried but that did not work

Comment: Turns out this works if i change applesList to an array

Answer (score 0):

Change `applesList` to an array.